# VBA loop problem - detect duplicated data in a line

Tags: excel, vba, loops

(Edit, it worked with these codes)

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 2 To 7252
Rows(x).Select
(codes to detect duplicates)
Next x
```

(End of the edit)

I have recorded this macro to detect duplicated data within a line :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

My data look like this

| 1 | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | apple | pear | banana | orange |
| 4 | **apple** | banana | **apple** | pear |

I want Excel to detect that in line 4 the data in column A et C are duplicats. I don't need it to detect duplications across diffferent lines.

Now I want it to repeat for all the 7252 lines.

I've tried different loop commands but with no success. I must have got de definition wrong somehow.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!
Rui

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Type:=xlExpression` to setup FC with formulas, then you don't have to loop through all rows.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, oFC As FormatCondition
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set oFC = Range("A2:D" & lastRow).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF(2:2,A2)>1")
    oFC.SetFirstPriority
    With oFC.Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With oFC.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    oFC.StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```